# Is there a way to mount an external hard drive as a USB Flash Drive?

Tags: usb, emulation, hard-drive, usb-drive, usb-flash-drive

In order to avoid paying for an extra feature on a backup software, I need to mound my external hard drive as a USB Flash Drive. Windows automaticlly recognizes external hard drive as "Hard Drives" on My Computer. However, flash drives are recognized as "Devices with removeable storage". I need to mount my 3TB hard drive as a "Device with removable storage".

I am using Windows 7 Pro. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Filter Drivers to change functionally Removable Media as Fixed Disk (or vice versa) in Windows.

See http://agnipulse.com/2012/03/filter-drivers-removable-media-fixed-disk-windows

The appropriate driver for your case is `diskmod.sys` and using `USBHDDasUFD.bat`

Comment: This is a programming site.  A good answer would say something about how to create a filter driver, or at least the user-mode API for loading/querying drivers.